# Find number of times a value appears in a Python dict

Tags: python, json

I'm working with a nested dictionary:

```
{
"payload": {
    "existence_full": 1,
    "geo_virtual": "[\"56.9459720|-2.1971226|20|within_50m|4\"]",
    "latitude": "56.945972",
    "locality": "Stonehaven",
    "_records_touched": "{\"crawl\":8,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}",
    "address": "The Lodge, Dunottar",
    "email": "dunnottarcastle@btconnect.com",
    "existence_ml": 0.5694238217658721,
    "domain_aggregate": "",
    "name": "Dunnottar Castle",
    "search_tags": [
        "Dunnottar Castle Aberdeenshire",
        "Dunotter Castle"
    ],
    "admin_region": "Scotland",
    "existence": 1,
    "category_labels": [
        [
            "Landmarks",
            "Buildings and Structures"
        ]
    ],
    "post_town": "Stonehaven",
    "region": "Kincardineshire",
    "review_count": "719",
    "geocode_level": "within_50m",
    "tel": "01569 762173",
    "placerank": 65,
    "longitude": "-2.197123",
    "placerank_ml": 37.27916073464469,
    "fax": "01330 860325",
    "category_ids_text_search": "",
    "website": "http://www.dunnottarcastle.co.uk",
    "status": "1",
    "geocode_confidence": "20",
    "postcode": "AB39 2TL",
    "category_ids": [
        108
    ],
    "country": "gb",
    "_geocode_quality": "4"
},
"uuid": "3867aaf3-12ab-434f-b12b-5d627b3359c3"
}
```

I have to record the number of times 'Museum' appears in the dictionary. The code I wrote below wont print anything and Im not sure what Im missing. Is there another way to iterate through all the values in a dict and count how many times a certain value appears?

```
museum = {}
for i in range (0, len(json_file)):
    try: 
        record = json_file[i]['payload']
        for value in record.values():
            if value == 'Museum':
                museum +=1 
                print(museum)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Why do you catch all the exceptions instead of checking if a key exists? No wonder your code ``wont print anything``, you will not even see any errors.

Comment: `<dict> += 1` makes no sense, but you're suppressing the error with the broad `except`.

Comment: The dictionary you posted does not contain the word Museum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
import json
museum_count = 0
data = json.load(json_file)
for x in data:
    try:
        for value in data[x]['payload']:
            if value.lower() == "museum":
                museum_count+= 1
    except KeyError, e:
        print str(e)
```

Your code misses the KeyError exception. If you only use exception the code just keeps running (and skips everything) without telling you. As mentioned by others:

```
museum = {}
```

declares a dictionary, to count or do stuff with numbers you need a integer. You can declare a integer by for example:

```
my_int = 0
```

Comment: Im getting an error for the code above, is there something I need to import?
    except KeyError, e:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I just typed the code quick without testing as inspiration, I don't know your exact input.  You don't need to import something. If you needed to import something you would get a "can not find error". Maybe the indent is not good if you copy pasted the code.

Comment: Syntax error means simply that the sintax is wrong. Sintax is in other words the spelling for a programming language. For example you mis a ")" (closing parentaces) you get this error. Because the (spelling/sintax) rule is that you always need to close with a ")". Just recheck your code if you miss something.

Answer (score 0):

The code `museum = {}` declares a dictionary. 
 When you run the code `museum +=1` it should give the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'int'

If you want a counter then do something like `museum = 0`